# How to call a function by clicking or tapping anywhere on a page on iphone safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari, webview

I am trying to use jquery so that if I click anywhere on the page it will change the text of a div for the iphone browser.

I have the following:

```
<div id="alternative_text">traduit</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).click(function() {
    $('#alternative_text').text("second text");
});

</script>
```

With the following in the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine in my desktop browser however the moment I try this on the iphone, it does nothing.
What do I need to do to get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the fun, what give you $('body *').on('click',function(){...}); ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try targeting the body element:

```
$("body").click(function() {
    $('#alternative_text').text("second text");
});
```